# Fullscreen support for opera next?

Tags: jquery, fullscreen, opera

Is full-screen support for opera-next available?

This is what i'm trying

```
var elem = $("#Content");
if (elem === undefined) {
    return false;
}
return elem.requestFullscreen || elem.mozRequestFullScreen || elem.webkitRequestFullscreen;
```

I was hoping that `elem.webkitRequestFullscreen` would work in the new version of opera being that it is webkit(/blink?) based, but it doesn't.

Any ideas, or is it too early to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renew the Opera. In 15.0.1147.61 relese it's work =)))